# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component error on normal Text components

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web

I've set up a simple react native mobile app with Expo and have been adding some stuff (react-native-web and styled-components).

After running the code successfully in react-native-web I tried to continue on the app by running it on my Android again.

Suddenly it shows me multiple of these errors whenever I use a react-native Text component:
[image]

Running the same code with react-native-web still works fine.

I've also tried to revert my code to my initial setup (and clearing my node_modules) after the initing expo but running "yarn android" there gives me the exact same errors.

Also sometimes see this error, but have no idea if it's related:
[image]

**My App.tsx:**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Header = styled.Text`
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: green;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>GARDEN</Header>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Text>Garden</Text>
      <Text>No issues</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**babel.config.js**:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["module-resolver", {
        alias: {
          "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
        }
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.12",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "expo-cli": "^4.10.1",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was cached a while back.

Fixed it by clearing the cache by running:

```
expo start --android -c
```